# web service by nodejs and date appears with one day delay

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have created web service by node js and my database is PostgreSQL.I pass the date to nodejs method by postman and make the query in my database:

query = (
    `SELECT distinct created_date
        from scheduled_locations
        where user_id = $1
            and device_id = $2
            and created_date >= $3
            and created_date < $4
        order by created_date ASC`);

```
db.any(query, [resquest.userId, resquest.DeviceId, resquest.from, resquest.to])
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
    })
```

in vs console i got this result :

```
0:Object {created_date: Mon Sep 03 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight T…}
1:Object {created_date: Wed Sep 05 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight T…}
2:Object {created_date: Thu Sep 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight T…}
3:Object {created_date: Sat Sep 08 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight T…}
```

but in postman i got these date:

**postman json request:**

```
{
    "userId":"43dc5b31-2fcb-40e7-bfdb-df0f6bb163e4",
    "DeviceId":"89984320001359565694",
    "from":"2018-09-02 12:11:49.909Z",
    "to":"2018-10-03 13:11:49.910Z"
}
```

**postman response :**

```
[{"created_date":"2018-09-02T19:30:00.000Z"},{"created_date":"2018-09-04T19:30:00.000Z"},{"created_date":"2018-09-05T19:30:00.000Z"},{"created_date":"2018-09-07T19:30:00.000Z"}...
```

Postman shows **one day before** !!! why and how can I fix it?

I have directly make the query into PostgreSQL ide:

```
SELECT distinct created_date
from scheduled_locations
where user_id = '43dc5b31-2fcb-40e7-bfdb-df0f6bb163e4'
  and device_id = '89984320001359565694'
and created_date >= '2018-09-02 12:11:49.909Z'
and created_date < '2018-10-03 13:11:49.910Z'
order by created_date ASC;
```

And this is results:

```
2018-09-03
2018-09-05
2018-09-06
2018-09-08
2018-09-10
2018-09-11
2018-09-22
2018-09-25
2018-09-26
2018-09-29
2018-09-30
2018-10-02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman shows it in utc. In vs console it shows in GMT+0430. If you convert by adding 4.30h to 2018-09-02T19:30:00 it is 2018-09-03.

notice 000Z and GMT+0430 in vs console log and postman response

Comment: Ok dude but how could i fix it problem automatically ? is there any way? except add 4.30 h manually @Hashan Karunathilaka

Comment: in your postgres module configs in nodejs there is probably a param to pass expected timezone. You can try setting it to utc.